# libisl-15.dll not found while compiling the hello.cpp

Tags: mingw-w64

I installed the mingw32-gcc-g++-bin on windows 10. When I am compiling in windows 10, it is saying that `libisl-15.dll` ia not found.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<"hello";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me

```
C:\MinGW\bin
```

was missing in PATH environment variable.
adding that to PATH solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just downloaded the libisl-15.dll from the below link  and copied to c:\mingw\bin folder
[libisl-15.dll](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/libisl-15_dll.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try find the dll file on [dllme](https://www.dllme.com/) and save the file on winGW bin folder path (something like "C:\MinGW\bin").